# PackageManager: Expecting better updated system app for com.xyz.launcher; removing system app

Tags: android, android-source

I have system app resides in firmware, when i update app using `device policy manager` it gets updated everything works fine, but When I reboot the device, i lost device admin permission for some reason.

```
PackageManager: Expecting better updated system app for 
com.secure.launcher; removing system app.  Last known 
codePath=/data/app/com.xyz.launcher-D3UlMWKC0eq_RuAh9Yg5FQ==, 
versionCode=60606; scanned versionCode=132
```

from the AOSP I found the following comment

> /*
>                            * If the system app is both scanned and in the
>                            * disabled packages list, then it must have been
>                            * added via OTA. Remove it from the currently
>                            * scanned package so the previously user-installed
>                            * application can be scanned.
>                            */

yes it is true that package has updated via OTA but my app is still device owner app after reboot but it loses a `device Admin` permission. 
Anyone having any solution to this problem?

Comment: I know it was a long time ago but do you have any update about this?

Comment: I have another application with system permission. This other app activates the device admin of my first app saliently on every reboot.